# Ubuntu 16.04: Failed to start Light Display Manager

Tags: 16.04, unity, kernel, virtualbox, lightdm

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox 6.0. The hosting system is Windows 10.

Before everything started to fail, I've had installed VirtualBox 5.2.2. After that, there appeared a dialog inside of Ubuntu, that said, that there are updates of some applications and the kernel. I have updated those programs through that dialog. Then I have upgraded to VirtualBox 6.0.

After I restarted everything, Ubuntu started to show only the desktop wallpaper. Then I opened the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. I typed in `sudo service lightdm restart`, to restart `lightdm`. After pressing enter, the ubuntu appeared for about half of a minute and then this message came up:
[Message after lightdm restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJcWv.png)

I typed in `systemctl status lightdm.service` to see why it failed, then this shows up:
[Failed to start Light Display Manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKJPh.png)

**EDIT:**
Output of `journalctl -u lightdm`:
[journalctl -u lightdm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYsyy.png)

And now I do not know how to solve this error. It would be very helpful if somebody could help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you give the output of journalctl -u lightdm ?

Comment: I´ve put the result after "EDIT:"

Comment: Do you have VirtualBox 6.0.0 or 6.0.2?  I started having this problem (only desktop background shown) after upgrading to 6.0.2 (specifically after upgrading the guest additions). 6.0.0 worked just fine.

Comment: For now I downgraded to VB 6.0.0.  BTW it seems that the problems are with the guest additions only, when 3D acceleration is enabled. To be clear, I also have 16.04.

Comment: That didn´t work. But now I am not even able to get till the login. Ubuntu shows me only the terminal.